# How to set a new iPhone Backup Password for new backups

Tags: iphone, backup, password, keychain

Unfortunately, I have lost/forgotten the password for my old iPhone backups. I understand that I cannot access any old backups without having the password to those backups, but I want to be able to create usable backups going forward.

It seems as if that password is burned into the phone forever and that I cannot create a *useable* backup now or in the future without having the old password.

The only useful suggestion I have found is to Reset the phone, not clearing data, which some posts suggest will lose the keychain and Wifi passwords.

So if that's the only way, is there a way to separately backup the keychain  and Wifi passwords? Obviously I can't rely on the normal backup system.

Comment: First place to look for existing password is Keychain Access -> Login -> Passwords tab, search for "backup". There should be entry  "iOS Backup" (or something similarly named).

Comment: Based on experience, focused questions are better received than lengthy ones. I made a rather heavy-handed edit to focus on the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/108313 lists the steps Apple recommends. Would they work for you as well?

Comment: \\ I made a rather heavy-handed edit to focus on the actual problem you want to solve. – 
nohillside // -- Thanks. I appreciate the help. I have a tendency to overexplain (ask my wife!).

Comment: \\ First place to look for existing password is Keychain Access ... – 
Aivar Paalberg //
-- Thanks. That IS the first place I looked. There are four entries on my Mac for iOS backup an iPhone backup and between them there are two different passwords, neither one works for the backup of my wife's iPhone, only my iPhone and our shared iPad.

Comment: \\ support.apple.com/en-us/108313 lists the steps Apple recommends. Would they work for you as well? – 
nohillside // -- Thanks. That may be my last resort. The Apple support severely minimizes the damage of this alternative. That loses ALL Wifi passwords as well, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems as if that password is burned into the phone forever and
> that I cannot create a useable backup now or in the future without
> having the old password.
>
> The only useful suggestion I have found is to Reset the phone, not
> clearing data, which some posts suggest will lose the keychain and
> Wifi passwords.

The password is stored in the iPhone (and iCloud and local backups of the iPhone) until the setting is changed or a settings reset. Unfortunately, a settings reset is the only mechanism that Apple provides to clear out the iOS backup password setting.

@aivar-paalberg made a comment on your question which is a good one, that if you use a Mac, you can look in keychain access to see if the backup password was saved back when you made it. [I outline how to do that in this blog post trying to help people who have forgotten their iPhone backup password](https://deciphertools.com/support/knowledge-base/i-forgot-my-iphone-backup-password/#resetpassword:%7E:text=Here%27s%20how%20to%20look%20for%20your%20iPhone%20backup%20password%20in%20the%20Mac%20keychain%3A).

> So if that's the only way, is there a way to separately backup the keychain and Wifi passwords? Obviously I can't rely on the normal backup system.

I believe [iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/109016) and iCloud backups are your only alternative given your parameters. Even if we just stored the keychain from an iPhone backup, the iOS keychain is only backed up in the local backup if encrypted backups are enabled, and that keychain backup is encrypted with keys from the backup keybag. So it would still require the backup password to access.